# How to dynamically load a ComboBox each time when opening the list(PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, combobox

Have a `PowerShell` script with two ComboBoxes.

One Box's list is loading at the start of the script, and the second is depending on first box selection.

Is there any event/trigger that I can call on each time when the ComboBox is opened?

Something like:

```
$ComboBox1_IsDropDownOpen ={
    Do stuff//
}
```

Comment: Found this [link](https://info.sapien.com/index.php/guis/gui-controls/spotlight-on-the-combobox-control), but it's not helping much

Comment: From your link I would guess you want to react to the event: `SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: No, the index has not been changed...